# How to share folder from Ubuntu Server 14.04 using samba to 2 desktop, windows XP and Ubuntu in Virtual Box

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, samba

I have 3 image in my Virtual Box. Ubuntu Server, windows xp and ubuntu 12.04. FYI, i've already install samba in Ubuntu server and the problem is that im stuck when trying to share folder from ubuntu server to windows xp and ubuntu. I've tried to do some research from google to youtube but it doesn't showed what i want. So, to the people that are more experience about this thing, do kindly help me coz im just a student that want to learn more about this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this turorial [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)? At which point are you stalled?